# How to make play custom notification sound only once

Tags: android, notifications

I have created notification with custom sound ,vibration and some text message. But, I'm unable make notification to play custom sound only once.
In my case it keeps on playing until user pulls the drawer
Here is my code,

```
 public synchronized static void createNotification(Context context,
            String message, int soundFile, int notifyId) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DashBoardActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent;
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setContentTitle(
                        context.getResources().getString(
                                R.string.schoolezone_map_title))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setStyle(
                        new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message));

        Uri sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName()
                + "/" + soundFile);
        mBuilder.setSound(sound, 1);
        int mNotificationId = notifyId;
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
        // notification.sound = sound;
        notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, notification);
    }
```

Please advise me some solution, Useful helps will be highly appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok add this Flag

```
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;
```

from google Docs [Googlde Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE)

This means

FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE : It should be set if you want the sound and/or vibration play each time the notification is sent, even if it has not been canceled before that.

Comment: not working, it keeps on playing until I pull the drawer

Comment: notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE; this snippet is working for limiting to one time

Comment: '|=' should be '=', It is assignment not OR, Anyway, thanks for help