# Android notification keeps on repeating notification sound

Tags: android

Following is my notification generationg code, but the sound keeps on repeating until pull down the status bar to check it.

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
        Notification mNotification;
        final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, new Intent(ctx, HomeScreenTabbed.class), 0);

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        mBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(notificationTitle);
        mBuilder.setStyle(new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notificationBody));
        mBuilder.setContentText(notificationBody);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
        mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_pollen_notification);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mNotification = mBuilder.build();
        // set dismiss on click flags
        mNotification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make play custom notification sound only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801365/how-to-make-play-custom-notification-sound-only-once)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `mNotification.defaults` in place of `mNotification.flags`

Comment: you just prevented my app to get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the flag FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE to your mNotification.flags definition.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE

This should prevent it from sending the sound more than once.

Comment: This mutes the sound for all subsequent notifications. Additionally, I have to remove all the other flags , in order to make FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE work.

Answer (score 0):

Just this:

```
.setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
```